# Powershell Invoke-webrequest Integers not appearing

Tags: json, powershell, integer, httpwebrequest

In Powershell, when I use the invoke-webrequest cmdlet in my script, I get data returned in a JSON with a variety of data types. However, integers and dates do not seem to work correctly with the convertfrom-json cmdlet.

Here is an example of the code:

```
$json1 = Invoke-webrequest -URI $URI -Certificate $cert -Headers $header | convertfrom-json
```

A field located here should have numbers in it, and they do in the response before the pipeline to convertfrom-json:

```
Number = $json1.workers.workAssignments.Number
```

So, how can I extract the number and date fields? Preferably I would like to loop through and add every employee and every attribute to a datatable, disconnected recordset, pscustomobject, or psobject & then export to CSV. 
I have coded each of the above objects several different times, and none of them have I gotten the integers or dates to export correctly. So, in lieu of posting a bunch of my solutions I figured I would keep it basic with the above and ask how to get the variable out of $json1 that contains integers and into some object to export to CSV.

Comment: Everything is a string in JSON... Married to convertfrom?

Comment: "*However, integers and dates do not seem to work correctly with the convertfrom-json cmdlet.*" - yes they do, try it yourself in 10 seconds: `@(1,2,(get-date).Date,3) | ConvertTo-Json | convertfrom-json`. Seriously, post your data, post your code attempts, post a minimum viable example which demonstrates your problem. Programming is hard enough with a good specification, nobody is going to magically guess the perfect chain of commands to process your data without seeing your data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not married to convertfrom-json whatsoever.
Example JSON:

```
{
  "workers": [ {
          "associateOID": "xxxxxxxx",
          "workerID": {
                  "idValue": "xxxxxxxx"
                      },
          "legalName": {
                 "givenName": "Lebron",
                 "middleName": "King",
                 "familyName1": "James",
                  "formattedName": "James, Lebron King"
                       },
          "birthDate": "1985-01-01",
          "baseRemuneration": {
                    "payPeriodRateAmount": {
                    "amountValue": 25,000,000,
                    "currencyCode": "USD"
                              },
          "effectiveDate": "2016-01-01"}
```

When using convertfrom-json, that amount in "Amount Value" results in Zero no matter what method I use.